# R: programmatic alternative for tidyr::spread?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I have R data.frames that have varying amount of columns. The last column is numeric and the rest are character strings. I need to arrange them so that the last non-numeric column is spread. The difficulty is that I want to do this programmatically as I don't know the column names.

E.g.

```
df <- data.frame(varA = c("A1", "A1", "A2", "A2"),
                 varB = c("B1", "B2", "B1", "B2"),
                 val = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

I get where I want by

```
tidyr::spread(df, varB, val)
```

but I don't know how to achieve this when the name of the spread variable is not known.

E.g. this won't work:

```
tidyr::spread(df, names(df)[ncol(df) - 1], val)
```

I've tried `tidyverse` solutions, but base R would be just as fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`spread_` is deprecated starting in *tidyr 0.7.0* and programming in *tidyr* has been switched to tidy evaluation.  See [this article](http://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2017/08/tidyr-0.7.0/) for more background.

To use a character string within `spread`, you need the `sym` function from package *rlang* along with `!!` to unquote for evaluation.

```
spread(df, !!rlang::sym(names(df)[ncol(df) - 1]), val)

  varA B1 B2
1   A1  1  2
2   A2  3  4
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `spread_`

```
tidyr::spread_(df, names(df)[ncol(df) - 1], "val")
#    varA B1 B2
#1   A1  1  2
#2   A2  3  4
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed. Curiously this does not work with ifelse statement, E.g.: `df2 <- ifelse(ncol(df) == 2, df[,ncol(df)], tidyr::spread_(...))`. Fortunately `if() ... else()` structure works well.

Comment: @Antti Not clear about the condition, but you may try within the `spread` i.e. `tidyr::spread_(df, ifelse(ncol(df)==2, names(df)[ncol(df)-1], names(df)[1]), "val")`

Comment: @Antti `ifelse` "returns a value with the same shape as `test`" (from `?ifelse`). If your test is a vector with one element, like `ncol(df) == 2`, then `ifelse` will return a vector with one element, not a data frame. Use `if{} else{}` as you found use it to return a single value as in akrun's comment.

Comment: Thanks akrun and Gregor for comments! That makes sense now.